# How to return a function with nextjs firebase authentication, via context

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to setup authentication on my project for a while using firebase authentication. I am doing a Next.js project.

I am having issues where If I login and refresh the page, I have to login again, I found a partial solution which involves using contexts, but whenever I use it to login, I am getting type error login is not a function. I have attached 3 files I am using

here is my context file

```js
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { useFirebaseAuth } from "../firebase";

const authUserContext = createContext({
  authUser: null,
  loading: true,
  login: async () => {},
});

export function AuthUserProvider({ children }) {
  const Auth = useFirebaseAuth;

  return (
    <authUserContext.Provider value={Auth}>{children}</authUserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(authUserContext);
```

Here is my login page. If i just make the login as a regular export in the firebase Auth file, I dont get the error, i am able to login but the context doesnt get updated.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
// import { emailRegex } from "../components/Utilities/validations";
import { useAuth } from "../components/contexts/userContext";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { login, authUser } = useAuth();
  const [loading2, setLoading] = useState(false);

 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // validate(e.values);
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const user = await login(email, password);
      console.log(user.user);
      console.log(authUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };
};

export default Login;
```

and here is the firebase code I have. If I remove the login function from the scope of the useFirebaseAuth, I can just import the login normally and get a login token. However, it doesnt update the authUser. If I refresh the page, I have to login again.

```js
function useFirebaseAuth() {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const formatAuthUser = (user) => ({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
  });
  const authStateChanged = async (authState) => {
    if (!authState) {
      setAuthUser(null);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    const formattedUser = formatAuthUser(authState);
    setAuthUser(formattedUser);
    console.log("useAuth " + authUser?.email);
  };
  const login = (email, password) => {
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    console.log(promise);

    return promise;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged(authStateChanged);
    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return {
    authUser,
    loading,
    login,
  };
}
```